Bitmap in Kotlin with Jetpack, won't draw the correct size
This has been driving me crazy all day.  I have been trying to draw a full screen bitmap as the background for my custom view.  The bitmap resolution is 2312x1080 the code right before I draw it shows both my canvas that I'm in and my bitmap are also 2312x1080 (these two log functions).  But it keeps drawing the image so that the bottom and right are a little bit cut off. I made a checkerboard test image to check. For the life of me I can't figure out what's going wrong. Anyone have any ideas?
    Log.d("GridView", "Loaded bitmap dimensions - width: ${bitmap?.width}, height: ${bitmap?.height}")
    Log.d("GridView", "Canvas size - width: ${size.width}, height: ${size.height}")

    //draw the background image
    bitmap?.let { image ->
        drawImage(
            image = image,
            topLeft = Offset.Zero,

        )
    }

Here's a simplified example of the code I'm using. I can't quite draw a full screen resolution bitmap. It's always a bit off.
@Composable
fun GridView() {
val context = LocalContext.current // Retrieve the current context
// Initialize GridViewModel with context
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    GridViewModel.initialize(context)
}

// Remembered variables to store width and height
var widthPx by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var heightPx by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }


// Load the bitmap outside of BoxWithConstraints
val bitmap = remember(screenshotPath) {
    Log.d("screenshot", "path $screenshotPath")
    if (!screenshotPath.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(screenshotPath)?.asImageBitmap()

    } else {
        null
    }
}

BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
) {
    widthPx = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()
    heightPx = constraints.maxHeight.toFloat()


    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()

    ) {
        //draw the background image
        bitmap?.let { image ->
            drawImage(
                image = image,
                topLeft = Offset.Zero,

                )
        }

    }
}

}
this is probably useful too, it's my onCreate from my mainActivity. I'm trying to setup full screen which mostly seems to work?
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    enableEdgeToEdge()
    // Enable immersive mode with the modern API

    // Full-screen mode with WindowInsetsController for API 30+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)  // Let the content go edge-to-edge
        val controller = window.insetsController
        controller?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
        controller?.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
    setContent {
        AccessabilityTheme {
            Surface(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                // Use the CustomGridView Composable here
                GridView()
            }
        }
    }

}


Can you provide your Canvas section code? In your drawImage() function, I see there's nothing wrong in your code

Can you provide some more code context so that we can think better around it, Thanks!
